grep for whole word without matching apostrophe such as contractions
For example when I try to grep for the word won (past tense of win) with grep -w won I still get won't in the results, which is not exactly a whole word match.

You should ask a followup question if you want to also use -o to output the matching string as that would require a different solution from some of the answers that will produce the correct output based on what you're currently asking for (i.e. the matching line) but would need rework to handle outputting just won, especially given input like won won with multiple possible matches (and so multiple outputs) per line when -o is added.

It is a whole word match since ' (apostrophe) is not a word character and therefore marks the end of the word won as far as grep is concerned.
You could drop the -w and do your own word filtering instead:
grep -e '^won ' -e ' won ' -e ' won$' -e '^won$'

This would get you all lines that contain the space-delimited word won at the start of the line, in the middle of the line, or at the end of the line, as well as all lines that consist only of the word won.
Change the trailing space after the word to a selection of punctuation characters that you want to allow, e.g. [ ,.!?].  You can't unfortunately use [ [:punct:]] to catch space and all punctuation characters, as that most likely also includes the ' character that gave you the issue to start with.
Going the other route and deciding to remove false positives with a second grep can be a bit risky:
grep -w won | grep -v "won't"

... as this would potentially get rid of lines that contain both the word won't and the word won.

Pathological counter example: 'I won', I explained to my friend.

@ChrisDavies I would argue that quotes would be written with ", not ', to not end up with things like 'I won't', he said.

Sarah chipped in, "I overheard my friend saying, 'Make sure you win', and then a moment later, more quietly, 'at all costs'." - some writers use the single quotes inside double quotes for nested speech. I did say it was a pathological example

@ChrisDavies At some point, one has to realise that writing a parser for natural languages is not something you're likely to do with grep.

It's also a thing to use single quotes when talking about the words themselves and I recall hearing that one might use different quotes for the different translations when talking about translations, e.g. «The Finnish word "lumi" means 'snow'» (though which way the quotes were supposed to be then...?)

anyway, it might be worth mentioning that grep -w likely considers alphanumerics and the underscore as word chars, though I guess it's not a standard option so the could be variance. grep -E -e '(^| )won($| )' might help avoid repeating the word. Still would need to repeat the word delimiter, whatever one uses.

Sounds like you might want the following, using any POSIX grep:
grep -E "(^|[^[:alnum:]_'])won([^[:alnum:]_']|$)"


grep -w won is short for grep '\<won\>'¹, that is it matches on won preceded and followed by a word boundary, or in other words a won that is neither preceded nor followed by a word character, word characters being alphanumerics and underscore.
In perl regexps, as supported by some grep implementations with -P, that could be written more explicitly using look-around operators:
grep -P "(?<!\w)won(?!\w)"

Here, it looks like you want to add ' to the characters considered as word characters, so you just need to replace \w with [\w']
grep -P "(?<![\w'])won(?![\w'])"

In effect, that's functionally equivalent to @EdMorton's
grep -E "(^|[^[:alnum:]_'])won([^[:alnum:]_']|$)"

Or the POSIX BRE equivalent:
grep "^\(.*[^[:alnum:]_']\)\{0,1\}won\([^[:alnum:]_'].*\)\{0,1\}$"

grep -x "\(.*[^[:alnum:]_']\)\{0,1\}won\([^[:alnum:]_'].*\)\{0,1\}"

Now as @Kusalananda points out, that will fail to match in "He said `I won' emphatically".
Where ASCII ` (U+0060 GRAVE ACCENT) and ' (U+0027 APOSTROPHE) are used in place of ‘ (U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK), ’ (U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) as English quoting operators.
Then looking for won not followed by '<word-character> may be preferable:
grep -P "(?<![\w'])won(?!'?\w)"


¹ That's actually how it was implemented in 2BSD in the late 70s where that -w option was introduced; you'll find some slight variations in behaviour between implementations, which might be why that option (or \<, \> regexp operators or variants such as perl's \b or [[:<:]]/[[:>:]]) was never specified by POSIX even though it's supported by most.

But you can't tell whether a single quote after the word is from a contraction or whether it is an end quote, without further semantic parsing.

@Kusalananda, good point. See edit.
